# cannot convert from android.support.v7.app.ActionBar to android.app.ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I worked on an android project when i got to reinstall windows.
So after the pc-setup i wanted to continue programming.
I re-installed the adt bundle and created a new workspace and imported the old project. After many problems i worked through, iam stuck now with this error:
"cannot convert from android.support.v7.app.ActionBar to android.app.ActionBar"
the code worked in my old project just fine, but now...
it meows here:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

android:minSdkVersion="13"

android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Library appcompat_v7 added

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Cleaning the project doesnt help either...

Comment: Assuming you are using eclipse does the 'Android Support Library' show as installed in the 'Extras' section of the Android SDK Manager? Have you tried right-clicking the project, highlight 'Android Tools' and select 'Add Support Library...'?

Comment: Yes i'm using eclipse. The Android Support Library is checked as installed. And Add Support Library as you mentioned didnt help.

Comment: So i solved the problem by right-clicking on the error and using the Quick Fix. I can't answer my own question by now. So heres it in the comment...
It changed the Code to:

      android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

Answer (score 3):

Your `ActionBar` import is incorrect. You are importing the android `ActionBar` instead of the  support `ActionBar`. Use this import instead:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```